# Scala testing mocking implicit parameters?

Tags: unit-testing, scala, testing, scalatest, spray

I'm having a bit of a tough time trying to understand how to write tests in Scala when implicit parameters are involved.

I have the following (short version) of my code and test:

Implementation (Scala 2.10, Spray and Akka):

```
import spray.httpx.SprayJsonSupport._
import com.acme.ResultJsonFormat._

case class PerRequestIndexingActor(ctx: RequestContext) extends Actor with ActorLogging {
  def receive = LoggingReceive {
    case AddToIndexRequestCompleted(result) =>
      ctx.complete(result)
      context.stop(self)
  }
}


object ResultJsonFormat extends DefaultJsonProtocol {
  implicit val resultFormat = jsonFormat2(Result)
}

case class Result(code: Int, message: String)
```

Test (Using ScalaTest and Mockito):

```
"Per Request Indexing Actor" should {
    "send the HTTP Response when AddToIndexRequestCompleted message is received" in {
      val request = mock[RequestContext]
      val result = mock[Result]

      val perRequestIndexingActor = TestActorRef(Props(new PerRequestIndexingActor(request)))
      perRequestIndexingActor ! AddToIndexRequestCompleted(result)

      verify(request).complete(result)
    }
  }
```

This line, `verify(request).complete(result)` uses an implicit Marshaller to turn `Result` into JSON.

I can bring a marshaller in to scope by adding `implicit val marshaller: Marshaller[Result] = mock[Marshaller[Result]]` but when I run the test a different instance of Marshaller is used, so the verification fails.

Even explicitly passing the mock Marshaller to `complete` fails.

So, can any one advise how to create a mock object for an implicit parameter and make sure that instance is the one used?

Comment: How does explicitly passing the mock fail? Why would you want to use a mock marshaller in the first place? (I haven't used mockito so please excuse me if those are stupid questions)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a perfect situation to use a `Matcher` from Mockito for the marshaller arg.  You should not need to mock out the implicit marshaller.  All you really want to do is verify that `complete` was called with a `result` matching what you expected and also some instance of the marshaller.  First, if you haven't already done it, bring the Mockito matchers into scope with an import like so:

```
import org.mockito.Matchers._
```

Then, if you wanted reference matching on the result, you could verify like so:

```
verify(request).complete(same(result))(any[classOf[Marshaller[Result]]])
```

Or, if you wanted equals matching on result you could do:

```
verify(request).complete(eq(result))(any(classOf[Marshaller[Result]]))
```

The trick with matchers is that once you use one for one arg, you have to use them for all args, so that's why we have to use one for `result` too.

Comment: I had tried that too. Though I had not tried using the `same()` matcher. I'm not sure why (yet) the test passes when using `verify(request).complete(same(result))(any[classOf[Marshaller[Result]]])` but does not pass when using `verify(request).complete(eq(result))(any(classOf[Marshaller[Result]]))`. Thanks for your suggestion though, it helped :)

Comment: Because the request variable is itself a mock, and the eq matcher uses the equals method which has not been stubbed, you always get false thus no match. Same is a good fit here. If request was not a mock and instead some case class, eq might fit better

Comment: Thanks for the follow up. Apologies for not being clear. Using `eq` the test doesn't even compile. When I use `eq` the error message is "Type mismatch, expected: Marshaller[Boolean], actual: Marshaller[Result]". And it's an error on `any(classOf[Marshaller[Result]])`. I'm not 100% clear on why the error occurs? It's pretty odd.